# generating bootstrap standard errors for large number of scalars

Tags: stata, statistics-bootstrap

Suppose I have four scalars: call them `dea_1 dea_2 dea_3 dea_4`. They are output from a program  `samprogram` (not shown here).

Now I use the `bootstrap` command in Stata with these scalars to get bootstrapped standard errors.

```
set seed 123
bootstrap dea_1=r(dea_1)dea_2=r(dea_2)dea_3=r(dea_3)dea_4=r(dea_4), reps(100): samprogram
```

This is fine but in my original program, I calculate 30 scalars, `dea_1 dea_2 ... dea_30`. Now I want to avoid writing each of these 30 scalars in the `bootstrap` command and for this purpose I wrote a loop as follows:

```
set seed 234
forvalues i in 1(1)30{
local k dea_`i'
bootstrap dea_`k'=r(dea_`k'), reps(100): samprogram
}
```

This works, but gives the output for each scalar one at a time. However, I am looking for  code which avoids writing all scalars in the `bootstrap` command but still gives the output for all at the same time (i.e. like the output from the following command)

```
set seed 345
bootstrap dea_1=r(dea_1)dea_2=r(dea_2)dea_3=r(dea_3)dea_4=r(dea_4)[omitted]...dea_30=r(dea_30), reps(100): samprogram
```

Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This yields to building-up the contents of a local macro step-by-step.

```
set seed 123
forval i = 1/30 { 
    local call `call' dea_`i'=r(dea_`i') 
}
bootstrap `call', reps(100) : samprogram
```

If need be, blank out the macro beforehand by

```
local call
```

More discussion in http://www.stata-journal.com/sjpdf.html?articlenum=pr0005 [free .pdf]

(LATER) Note that contrary to your assertion the code

```
set seed 234
forvalues i in 1(1)30{
local k dea_`i'
bootstrap dea_`k'=r(dea_`k'), reps(100): samprogram
}
```

would not work as intended. First time round, for example, `bootstrap` would be looking for `r(dea_dea_1)` and would return missing for every sample. The code for calling `bootstrap` repeatedly could simply be

```
set seed 234
forvalues i = 1/30 {
    bootstrap dea_`i'=r(dea_`i'), reps(100): samprogram
}
```

but that would be a bad idea when you can do what you want in one call.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative solution would be to make your program `eclass` and return the results in the matrix `e(b)`. This allows the shortcut `bootstrap _b, reps(100): samprogram`. Below is an example. The key points here are that the different scalars are stored in the row vector `` `b' ``, which is returned by the program as the row vector `e(b)` whith the command:

```
ereturn post `b', esample(`touse')
```

A complete example is here:

```
clear all

program define sim, eclass
    syntax varlist(numeric) [if] [in], by(varname numeric) 
    marksample touse
    markout `touse' `by'

    local k : word count `varlist'
    tempname b m0
    matrix `b' = J(1,`k',.)

    local i = 1
    foreach var of local varlist {
        sum `var' if `touse' & `by', meanonly
        scalar `m0' = r(mean)
        sum `var' if `touse' & !`by', meanonly
        matrix `b'[1,`i'] = `m0' - r(mean)
        local i = `i' + 1
    }
    ereturn post `b', esample(`touse')

end

sysuse auto
bootstrap _b, reps(100) : sim price mpg length weight trunk, by(foreign)
```

Comment: Thanks Maarten for pointing to that direction. In fact, there is also a help file [here](http://www.stata.com/support/faqs/statistics/bootstrapping-vectors/) which I didn't notice earlier.