# How to use `if` with local macro in Stata?

Tags: if-statement, local, stata

I am trying to assign values of `income` in 2012 to locals. So that local `val_AK` would have value of `income` in state "AK", `val_AL` would have value of `income` in state "AL".... Here is the [Stata 11 version of .dta](http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/41007907/states.dta)

The following code generates `AK not found r(111);` However `AK` does exist in `state_nsw`, which is a string variable:

```
foreach i in "AK" "AL" "AR" "AZ" {
     if (state_nsw=="`i'" & year==2012) { local val_`i'=income}
     }
```

I also tried using [this method](http://www.stata.com/statalist/archive/2004-03/msg00928.html) and this:

```
if (state_nsw=="`i'" ...
...
// and got invalid name r(198)
```

Where is my mistake?

Comment: Where is `j` defined? Please give us sample data to work.

Comment: Thank you @Metrics for reply. `j` is the local for the year...i will correct the code above...we can ignore j...it works fine...i have just corrected the code

Comment: I am sorry. Are you still getting the error?

Comment: Yes, i don't know why...I think this has to do something with "`AK'"

Comment: Do you have the sample data to post?

Comment: I tried `count if state_nsw=="AK"` and got `36`, so this works...but how come state_nsw==`i' throws an error?

Comment: Here is my `dta': https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/41007907/states.dta  thank you

Comment: I can't open the file; it seems you are using the Stata 12 which I don't have. Please explain what you are trying to do.

Comment: I am trying to assign values of `income` to locals. So that local `val_AK` would have value of income in state "AK", `val_AL` would have value of income in state "AL". Here is the Stata 11 vesion of `.dta` https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/41007907/states.dta

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As `state_nsw` is a string variable it can only be compared with either a literal string or another string variable.

Simplifying down to the first value in your loop

```
foreach i in "AK" {
    if (state_nsw == `i' & year == 2012) { local val_`i'=income }
}
```

the inner statement is interpreted as

```
    if (state_nsw == AK & year == 2012) { local val_AK = income }
```

Now as far as Stata is concerned `AK` is not a literal string, so it can only be the name of a string variable. But you have no such variable, which is why you got the error you did. What would have been more appropriate would have been

```
    if (state_nsw == "AK" & year == 2012) { local val_AK = income }
```

or, more generally,

```
   if (state_nsw == "`i'" & year == 2012) { local val_`i'=income }
```

So, why did you get the error `invalid name r(198):`

```
 foreach i in "AK" "AL" "AR" "AZ" {
         if (state_nsw=="`i'" & year==2012) { local val_`i'=income}
         }
```

I can't answer that from looking at your code, but see below.

Your troubles are not over yet. Your code is very confused.

- The `if` statement will be interpreted with reference to the first observation. This is explained at http://www.stata.com/support/faqs/programming/if-command-versus-if-qualifier/
- Similarly

  ```
  local val_`i' = income
  ```

will always be interpreted as

```
    local val_`i' = income[1]
```

regardless of the `if` command.

- Placing `{ }` on the same line after `if` has been out-of-date since version 8 and may not work as you wish.

What should work is

```
  foreach i in AK AL AR AZ { 
      su income if year == 2012 & state_nsw == "`i'", meanonly 
      local val_`i' = r(mean) 
  }
```

although why you want to do that is a puzzle.

Comment: Also, check whether `year` is a string variable.

Comment: Thank you. But it works not the way i wanted: the local `val_AL` does not exist. I tried: recode income_nsweight .= `val_AL' and i got an error that "val_AL" is unidentified.

Comment: That's meaningless. You perhaps meant `\`val_AL'` or `\`val_AK'` When you refer to local macros you need open and close quote marks.

Comment: Yes, that is what i meant. it is a typo

Comment: I tried: recode income_nsweight .= "`val_AL'" -- and get unknow el in rule

Comment: Now you are trying to `recode` a numeric variable with string values. Won't work. Also, new questions should be new questions, not comments.

Comment: I have provide detail in the new question for clarity http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17266287/how-to-create-locals-on-the-fly-in-stata

Answer (score 2):

I can't still open the data. Try following:

```
foreach i in "AK" "AL" "AR" "AZ"{
    gen val_`i'=income if state_nsw=="`i'" & year==2012
    local val `val' val_`i'
    }

Sample data and output: 
state   val year
AK  13  2010
AL  112 2010
AR  12  2010
AZ  14  2010


    val_AK  val_AL  val_AR  val_AZ  
    13              
            112         
                    12      
                             14
```

Comment: @Metrics That won't work. At best `val` will just contain the last string copied to it, `val_AZ`, which is no use.

Comment: I got it to work, but the problem is that `val` contains the string, but the value of income

Comment: @Nick:Thanks.As per your solution [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17138521/generating-bootstrap-standard-errors-for-large-number-of-scalars), this has been now corrected.

Comment: @Metrics Still won't work. You are accumulating string values (variable names), not the numeric values they contain. Also, trying to put a numeric variable in a macro is futile in any case.

Comment: You could do that more concisely with `separate`. OP wants values in locals for some reason.