# How to create locals on the fly in Stata?

Tags: local, stata

I am trying to create locals on the fly and check them by assigning values to a new variable

```
gen sampleVar =.

foreach i in AK AL  AR  AZ {
 su income if (year==2012 & state_nsw == "`i'"), meanonly
local val_`i' = r(mean)
display "`val_`i''"
}

 // check the local
 recode sampleVar .= "`val_AL'" 
 // this is what I get:
 5242.57421875
 .....
 5352.66796875
 . invalid name
 r(198);

 // check 2 the local
 recode sampleVar .= `val_AL'  // error
```

ANSWER: My problem was that I tried

```
 recode sampleVar .= `val_AL' + `val_AZ'
// this is inappropriate.
//the correct way is:
local try = `val_AL' + `val_AZ'
recode sampleVar .= `try'
```

Comment: Surprisingly to me, `recode` tolerates the " ". I don't know what the error is in the second statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be clear that your `local`s must be in the same name space, i.e. interactive session, do-file, do-file editor, program. To debug, type

```
macro li
```

before the `recode` statement to see what macros are visible.

Comment: 1) `val_GA` is a typo, i am copypasting from the 51 states, i have corrected for this in the question. 2) But local `val_AL` contains a value, i check it with: display "`val_AL`", it was 563.23. Why can't i do: recode sampleVar .= 'val_AL'?

Comment: Another typo, I guess. Should be `\`val_AL'` as already pointed out.

Comment: Do you really want to replace all missing values with the value for Alaska in 2012?

Comment: I have other conditions...if...and loops...I narrowed down my code to show the problematic places. But i still can't figure out how come recode doesn't execute: i checked `val_AL` it contains a numeric value. `sampleVar` contains missing values. It should work

Comment: Edit your question. Show code sufficient to reproduce your entire problem. Include the results of `macro list`.